# Обмен личными сообщениями

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица `messages` и в ней следующие поля. `id`, `toid`, `fromid`, `hash`, `status`, `date`. Собственно сам вопрос. Как реализовать следующее. Нужно отобразить последнюю переписку с пользователями, вывести как в Вконтакте. Т.е к примеру, я юзер с ид 1, кто-то юзер с ид 2, а кто-то третий с ид 3. Я переписывался  с ними и мне нужно вывести последнюю переписку с этими пользователями.

Answer (score 1):

Так:

```
select max(id) as id, opponentid
from (
  select max(id) as id, toid as opponentid
  from messages
    where fromid = $id
  group by toid
  union all
  select max(id), fromid
  from messages
    where toid = $id
  group by fromid
) opponents
group by opponent
```

Непосредственно текст сообщения (и прочие необходимые атрибуты) получается из соединения `messages` с данным запросом по `id`.

ЗЫ Про индексы по `toid` и `fromid` (в отдельности) не забудьте.

Answer (score 0):

Из дешевого можно просто, при отправке сообщения помимо самого сообщения, сохранять в отдельную таблицу лист с id переписок. То есть id последних сообщений с разными авторами. И уже по массиву этих id выдирать конкретные сообщения, и показывать. То есть смысл в том, что бы вам не вычислять последнюю пару сообщений **из всех**, а непосредственно во время создания этих сообщений определять их или переопределять где то, как последние.